# TypeError: abc.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the following code:

```
  <span class="map-marker" data-lng="101.7113506794"></span>
  <span class="map-marker" data-lng="101.6311097146"></span>

  var abc = $('.map-marker:first');
  var xyz = abc.getAttribute("data-lat");
  console.log(xyz);
```

I get the error message: `TypeError: abc.getAttribute is not a function`. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try abc.attr(), I am not sure whether the reference :first will point correct. I think you better have both span wihin one div.

Comment: Probably a typo, but your spans have a data-lng attribute, not a data-lat attribute

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this may be:

```
var abc = $(".map-marker:first")[0];
var xyz = abc.getAttribute("data-lat");
console.log(xyz);
```

Or this:

```
var abc = $(".map-marker:first");
var xyz = abc.data("lat");
console.log(xyz);
```

Answer (score 24):

`abc` is a jQuery object, so it doesn't have a `getAttribute()` function. it has an `attr()` function.

Answer (score 10):

> What have I done wrong?

You treated a *jQuery object* like a *DOM element*. jQuery objects don't have a `getAttribute` method. You can either use [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead.

Answer (score 4):

You are selecting multiple elements. The select function returns an array, and the array does not have a getAttribute function. You can use a for loop to iterate through the selection and get the attribute values, or you could use an indexer ([0], for example) to get the attribute of a particular one.

Comment: *"You are selecting multiple elements."* Actually no. The `:first` pseudo selector reduces the set to one element. *"The select function returns an array"* No, it returns a jQuery object. *"and the error does not have a getAttribute function"* Uh? jQuery objects (or arrays) don't have a `getAttribute` method, that's correct

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I am new to jQuery, so sort of assumed because the result of a $() selection is integer indexed and has length and so on, it is an array. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/ tells me it is not. But does a jQuery object implement all the methods of an array? I could not find it in the documentation.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It implements only some array methods, like `.sort`, but they don't seem to be properly documented.

Answer (score 3):

Your trying to get "data-lat" but you only have "data-lng" defined.

Answer (score 2):

Just got into this problem. Agree with @Felix Kling
Try below:

```
<span class="map-marker" data-lng="101.7113506794"></span>
<span class="map-marker" data-lng="101.6311097146"></span> 

<script>
var abc = $('.map-marker:first');
var xyz = $(abc).attr("data-lng");
console.log(xyz);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep an eye out for accessing `this` in an event handler with dynamic scope.

Calling a function on `this` that does not exist can cause `node.getAttribute is not a function`.

Comment: How to solve this ?

Comment: Don't use `this`. Based on the code in this question initially you would use javascript rather than jQuery to get the element.

Answer (score 0):

`NamedNodeMap`s can be a little challenging. The `find` method sometimes returns attributes inside an element in `NamedNodeMap` type which is also convertible to array; but alternatively it is possible to directly read the `nodeValue`. Taking an XML-RSS2 Feed as an example, for each `item` in the feed which featured image is available by the tag `<media:content url="the_value_here">`, reading the value is possible by pointing to `rss_item.find("media\\:content")[0]['attributes']['url'].nodeValue`, which is a pure method. Follow your console dump to find the best practice in your case.